# Make a helix made of helixes using blender and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, helix

I want to make a singe helix that is slightly curved so i can generate them in unity to make a bigger helix out of that helix. I tried doing it in blender using the screw to make the first helix and then add the curve modifier. I attached a spiral to the curve modifier. After all this im pretty sure i generated the small helices correctly in unity but they are not lining up correctly. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this. I want control of each of the smaller helices in unity.

Here is my unity code:

```
#pragma strict

var day : Transform;
function Start () {
    var angle_difference =  365/360;
    var x = 0.0;
    var y = 0.0;
    var z = 0.0;
    var x_angle = 0.0;
    var a = 0.0;
    var radius = 17.43;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 720; i++) {
        a = angle_difference * i;
        x = radius * Mathf.Cos((a * Mathf.PI)/180);
        y = radius * Mathf.Sin((a * Mathf.PI)/180);
        z = (i/360.0) * 10.0;
        x_angle = a+90;
        Instantiate(day, Vector3 (x, z, y), Quaternion.Euler(Vector3(0, 0, 0)));
    }
}
function Update () {

}
```

im trying to make 365 helices around. 
The inner circle of the helix has radius = .1 
The radius of the single helix is .5 and the height is .3. 
The radius of the full helix im trying to create should be 17.43 and the height of the full helix should be 3

Comment: There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30417749/edit) button to update the info given in the main question part.